# android : diff b/w com.example.MyImageView and ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

//Can anyone explain me what the diff b/w these two?  I would really appreciate your reply.

```
 <com.example.MyImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:layout_weight="50" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Comment: What's your declaration of `com.example.MyImageView`?

Comment: `com.example.MyImageView` is certainly not part of android API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is referring to some custom widget named `com.example.MyImageView`. The other is referring to the standard Android `ImageView` widget.